# Implementing a public protocol with internal class in swift

Tags: swift, swift2

So I'm writing a Swift framework where I want to expose some objects publicly only through a `protocol`.

eg:

```
public protocol Thing : class {
    var x : Int { get }
}
```

I want to hide my implementation details so I make an `internal` class:

```
internal class ThingImpl : Thing {
    public private(set) var x : Int = 0
}
```

And vend out new `Things` via a factory method:

```
public func newThing() -> Thing {
    return ThingImpl()
}
```

What I can't understand is why the compiler warns me about making `var x` `public` within `ThingImpl` and encourages me to declare it internal.

[image]

Everything runs fine despite the warning, and if I heed the warning and change to `internal private(set) var x : Int = 0` the warning goes away and things still run fine.

It seems to me that making the var public is the right thing to do since it is public in the public protocol it is implementing.
Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ThingImpl` is an internal class. So it will override the accessibility of the public `x` variable, effectively making this variable internal. So, set the accessibility of this variable to `public` is redundant.

Comment: But it is public by virtue of the Thing protocol right?

Comment: If you access this through the `Thing` protocol, it's public. But you cannot access `x` through `ThingImpl` from other modules. I meant, two cases are not related

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's them not being related I'm finding it hard to come to terms with. I mean, ThingImpl is declared to confirm to Thing (which is public) therefor it must have a public var x : Int { get }. Argh! :)

Answer (score 0):

With [this](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=5) in mind:

- private: available only to its source file
- internal: available to its entire module
- public: available to everyone

Your implementation class:

```
internal class ThingImpl : Thing {
    <#access#> var x : Int = 0
}
```

Access control possibilities:

- `private`: not possible, x needs to have read access to conform to Thing (the properties in the protocol are public by design)
- `public`: not much sense in an internal class, it compiles though (with a warning)
- `private(set)`: it will allow modifying x in the same source file only
- `internal`: is the default if you don't put any access control, it will allow modifying x in the same module (framework, target, etc.)
- `public private(set)`: Making a variable `public` and `private` at the same time doesn't make much sense, does it?. Even less if it's inside an `internal` class.

IMHO there are two reasonable options:

- Don't include any access control and let x be writable in the module
- Use `private(set)` to restrict the write access to its file

Comment: Yes, the thing is though that adopting the public protocol makes the variable readable publicly.

Comment: `public private(set)` makes sense because I want the public interface (protocol) to contain a readonly variable but to be able to modify it in my private/internal implementation.

Comment: The `x` in thing is read only (you only included `get` in its declaration). Using `internal` (or just blank) you are able to do exactly that: `x` is readable because Thing declares it that way, and it's internally writable (in the same module).